# NodeJS, Typescript: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I tried to set up a backend with ExpressJS and Typescript but failed.
When I run `nodemon --exec node --loader ts-node/esm src/index.ts`, the console showed: "Cannot find module..."
I exported app in **app.ts** like this

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
export default app;
```

and then imported in **index.ts** file

```
import app from './app';
...
```

I already set "type": "module" in **package.json**
And this is my **tsconfig.json** file

```
"compilerOptions": {
  {
   "target": "ESNext",  
   "module": "ESNext",                                
   "rootDir": "./src/",                                  
   "moduleResolution": "node",  
  }
},
"include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `type=module`, you need to add the `.js` extension, see [type in package.json and New Extensions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html#type-in-packagejson-and-new-extensions).

Try

```
import app from './app.js';
```